# Passing arguments to parallel processing in xargs

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, xargs

What is the purpose of `xargs_tasks` in the following command?:

```
cat source.ndjson | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 8 sh -c './theprocess.py $1' xargs_tasks >> errors.log 2>&1
```

Namely, after reading the man page details of the `-c` option to `sh`, you can actually get the same results by running:

```
cat source.ndjson | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 8 sh -c './theprocess.py $0' >> errors.log 2>&1
```

That is, with `-c`, any arguments that come after the string in quotes are assigned to the variables `$0`, `$1`, and so forth. `xargs_tasks` in the first command is set to `$0`, and the arguments piped to `xargs` one at a time get set to `$1`. Hence my second command works exactly the same since I directly have `$0` inside the string instead of `$1`.

My guess was that `xargs_tasks` gives you a short string to filter with in something like `htop`, but that's a stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `-c` option to `sh`, the next argument after the command is taken as `$0` in the command, and the arguments after it become `$1`, `$2`, etc.

`$0` is supposed to contain the name of the shell script, while arguments start at `$1`. So `xargs_task` is there just to be a placeholder to prevent the first argument from being put into `$0`.

Comment: So you believe the first command uses `xargs_tasks` merely to follow the standard convention of variable naming in bash scripting? Seems reasonable.

Comment: Yes. It's more useful in the general case where the command uses all the arguments in something like `"$@"`, because `$0` isn't included in that.

Comment: I think there also may be some variation between different shells in what they do with the argument after the command. I remember seeing a style where people write `-exec sh -c "command" {} {}` because some shells use the first argument and some use the second.

Comment: @shogekiha Accepting the answer is better than upvoting.